# Java: how to unsubscribe a durable subscriber from Spring's DMLC?

Tags: java, spring-jms

In plain JMS we can do: session.unsubscribe("name of the durable subscription"); but how do we do it through DMLC? Couldn't find any specific method for this purpose in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no Spring specific way of sending an "unsubscribe" command to the MQ server, however you always have the option of obtaining an underlying JMS Session by extending the [`DefaultMessageListenerContainer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html) class and calling [`getSession()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.html#getSession%28org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsResourceHolder%29) or [`createSession()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/support/JmsAccessor.html#createSession%28javax.jms.Connection%29). After all Spring is just a convenient abstraction over the top of JMS and doesn't prevent you from using the JMS API directly if required.