# Is it possible to stop and restart a durable subscription using spring jms?

Tags: java, spring, publish-subscribe, spring-jms

I'm using the following DefaultMessageListenerContainer to create a durable subscription to get messages even in downtimes which really works well.

```
@Bean
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    SingleConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new SingleConnectionFactory(new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
            AMQ_BROKER_URL));
    connectionFactory.setClientId(CLIENT_ID);
    return connectionFactory;
}

@Bean
DefaultMessageListenerContainer container(final MessageListener messageListener,
        final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return new DefaultMessageListenerContainer() {
        {
            setMessageListener(messageListener);
            setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
            setDestinationName(JMS_TARGET);
            setPubSubDomain(true);
            setSessionTransacted(true);
            setSubscriptionDurable(true);
            setDurableSubscriptionName(SUBSCRIPTION_ID);                        
            setConcurrentConsumers(1);
        }
    };
}
```

The question is: What is the best way to remove the subscription when I don't need it anymore? Would it even be possible to temporarily remove the subscription (and miss some messages), but enable it later again?

The only way which worked so far, was to shutdown the DMLC and call unsubscribe afterwards.

```
dmlc.shutdown();
Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
session.unsubscribe(SUBSCRIPTION_ID);
```

Is that a sensible solution? How could the subscription be reinitiated?

I've already seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408631/java-how-to-unsubscribe-a-durable-subscriber-from-springs-dmlc) but I really don't know how to do this? Or would it be even better to subscribe and unsubscribe in a total different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I suggest my answer, allow me a word of caution: temporarily removing a durable subscription sounds a little bit like you don't really need a durable subscription. Durable subscriptions are for `Consumers` which need to receive messages that were sent while they are offline. If you need the messages only sometimes (say, when your consumer is connected), a non-durable topic is the item of choice.

Note that this only makes sense for `Topics` (1:n communication, pub/sub). `Queues` work slightly different as they are used for 1:1 communication (advanced techniques like load balancing set aside for now).

Durable topics incur a notable resource overhead on the message broker and removing and recreating subscriptions might lead to expensive initialization over and over again.

Now if you really want to (temporarily) unsubscribe from your durable topic (also works for "normal" topics), you'll have to extend `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`:

```
public class MyContainer extends DefaultMessageListenerContainer {
    public Session retrieveSession() {
        return getSession(); // this is protected, so we wrap it (could also make getSession public)
    }
}
```

When you instantiate `MyContainer` (instead of `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`) in the `container` method, make sure to store the reference:

```
protected MyContainer listenerContainer;
...
listenerContainer = new MyContainer(...);
return listenerContainer;
```

You can then just call `listenerContainer.retrieveSession().unsubscribe(...)` to unsubscribe.

Please also note that you may only call this after all the session's consumers to that topic are closed and there are no messages in transit (direct quote from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Session.html#unsubscribe%28java.lang.String%29): "It is erroneous for a client to delete a durable subscription while there is an active (not closed) consumer for the subscription, or while a consumed message is part of a pending transaction or has not been acknowledged in the session."

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I agree with your concerns about un-/ subscribe over and over again, but I'm currious how this could work. It would not a daily operation. Thus the question remains: What is the best way to un-/ subcribe manually. Your suggestion 'only' unsubscribe, but I'm still having a problem with this since getSession needs a JmsResourceHolder instance. In addition, although I could not test your solution, I think I will also get an error because the consumer would be still active. That's why I needed to call dmlc.shutdown() before in "my proposal".

Comment: you will still have to modify your approach, since you're creating a totally new session (which will get its own client id) and thus you're not unsubscribing from the same session that issued the subscription: your old subscription will remain active

Comment: Are you sure? The clientId is set in the connectionFactory, thus I thought the session would get the same clientId. Nevertheless, how can I get the original session? As stated before, I would need a JmsResourceHolder instance, right?

Comment: I didn't know that you set the clientID in the factory ;) Nevertheless you can always store a reference to your session or obtain it with above method, for which you need a ResourceHandler, but I don't know a method out of the top of my head how to obtain one.

Comment: Hmmm...okay, so how to get the session in the first place. Let me rephrase the question: What would be the best or easiest way to subscribe (durable) and unsubscribe to a topic? Are there benefits using the DMLC in this case in the first place?

Comment: Well the easiest (as in: fastest) way to subscribe is using the JMS API directly, without Spring. If your application is somewhat large and you find resource pooling beneficial for performance (it usually is) then Spring (DMLC) might be easiest, it always depends. The benefits of DMLC are that it takes care of some things you'd otherwise have to do manually (resource pooling, automatic reconnection etc.). The problem this higher abstraction gives you less control. And what you're trying to do is against the usually semantics, thus, hard to do in the Spring framework.

Comment: Okay. Especially the reconnect is really beneficial. Thus I think I will use the DMLC and completely ignore the unsubscribe process as you suggested. As I just saw, it is also possible to delete the subscription in the broker admin application. If an application/ module with a durable subscription is not needed anymore, I will delete the subscription there after the module has been shutdown. ;-) Thanks!